# How to run VBA macros in powerpoint without presentation mode

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to make a powerpoint template that features certain buttons to run VBA macros. Currently the ActiveX buttons I have will only run when the powerpoint is in presentation mode. Is there a way to activate the buttons or execute the macros in another easy way from design mode in the slides?